# GaussianFilter implimation in JNI Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, gaussian

I am try to implemented java fast blur algorithm into JNI here code and error attached this code give some unexpected error so please any one give me suggestion what's wrong thing I am doing in this code.

**Error :**

**Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xaeac7f68 in tid 32367**

**Code :**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_xyz_selection_ImgPro_ImgPro_gaussianFilter(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                          jintArray in_, jintArray out_, jint width,
                                                          jint height, jint radius) {
    jint *in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in_, NULL);

    int wm = width - 1;
    int hm = height - 1;
    int wh = width * height;
    int div = radius + radius + 1;

    jintArray rr = env->NewIntArray(wh);
    jint *r = env->GetIntArrayElements(rr, NULL);
    jintArray gg = env->NewIntArray(wh);
    jint *g = env->GetIntArrayElements(gg, NULL);
    jintArray bb = env->NewIntArray(wh);
    jint *b = env->GetIntArrayElements(bb, NULL);

    int rSum, gSum, bSum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;

    jintArray vMinArray = env->NewIntArray((jint) fmax(width, height));
    jint *vMin = env->GetIntArrayElements(vMinArray, NULL);

    int divSum = (div + 1) >> 1;
    divSum *= divSum;

    jintArray dvArray = env->NewIntArray(256 * divSum);
    jint *dv = env->GetIntArrayElements(dvArray, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < 256 * divSum; i++) {
        dv[i] = (i / divSum);
    }

    yw = yi = 0;

    jintArray sirArray;
    int stackPointer;
    int stackStart;
    int rbs;
    int r1 = radius + 1;
    int routSum, goutSum, boutSum;
    int rinSum, ginSum, binSum;

    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        rinSum = ginSum = binSum = routSum = goutSum = boutSum = rSum = gSum = bSum = 0;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            p = in[yi + (jint) fmin(wm, (jint) fmax(i, 0))];
            sirArray = env->NewIntArray(i + radius);
            jint *sir = env->GetIntArrayElements(sirArray, NULL);
            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
            rbs = r1 - (jint) fabs(i);
            rSum += sir[0] * rbs;
            gSum += sir[1] * rbs;
            bSum += sir[2] * rbs;
            if (i > 0) {
                rinSum += sir[0];
                ginSum += sir[1];
                binSum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routSum += sir[0];
                goutSum += sir[1];
                boutSum += sir[2];
            }
            env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(sirArray, sir, 0);
        }
        stackPointer = radius;

        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {

            r[yi] = dv[rSum];
            g[yi] = dv[gSum];
            b[yi] = dv[bSum];

            rSum -= routSum;
            gSum -= goutSum;
            bSum -= boutSum;

            stackStart = stackPointer - radius + div;
            sirArray = env->NewIntArray(stackStart % div);
            jint *sir = env->GetIntArrayElements(sirArray, NULL);

            routSum -= sir[0];
            goutSum -= sir[1];
            boutSum -= sir[2];

            if (y == 0) {
                vMin[x] = (jint) fmin(x + radius + 1, wm);
            }
            p = in[yw + vMin[x]];

            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

            rinSum += sir[0];
            ginSum += sir[1];
            binSum += sir[2];

            rSum += rinSum;
            gSum += ginSum;
            bSum += binSum;

            env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(sirArray, sir, 0);

            stackPointer = (stackPointer + 1) % div;
            sirArray = env->NewIntArray((stackPointer) % div);
            sir = env->GetIntArrayElements(sirArray, NULL);

            routSum += sir[0];
            goutSum += sir[1];
            boutSum += sir[2];

            rinSum -= sir[0];
            ginSum -= sir[1];
            binSum -= sir[2];

            yi++;
            env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(sirArray, sir, 0);
        }
        yw += width;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        rinSum = ginSum = binSum = routSum = goutSum = boutSum = rSum = gSum = bSum = 0;
        yp = -radius * width;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            yi = (jint) fmax(0, yp) + x;

            sirArray = env->NewIntArray(i + radius);
            jint *sir = env->GetIntArrayElements(sirArray, NULL);

            sir[0] = r[yi];
            sir[1] = g[yi];
            sir[2] = b[yi];

            rbs = r1 - (jint) fabs(i);

            rSum += r[yi] * rbs;
            gSum += g[yi] * rbs;
            bSum += b[yi] * rbs;

            if (i > 0) {
                rinSum += sir[0];
                ginSum += sir[1];
                binSum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routSum += sir[0];
                goutSum += sir[1];
                boutSum += sir[2];
            }

            if (i < hm) {
                yp += width;
            }

            env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(sirArray, sir, 0);
        }
        yi = x;
        stackPointer = radius;

        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            in[yi] = (0xff000000 & in[yi]) | (dv[rSum] << 16)
                     | (dv[gSum] << 8) | dv[bSum];

            rSum -= routSum;
            gSum -= goutSum;
            bSum -= boutSum;

            stackStart = stackPointer - radius + div;
            sirArray = env->NewIntArray(stackStart % div);
            jint *sir = env->GetIntArrayElements(sirArray, NULL);

            routSum -= sir[0];
            goutSum -= sir[1];
            boutSum -= sir[2];

            if (x == 0) {
                vMin[y] = (jint) fmin(y + r1, hm) * width;
            }
            p = x + vMin[y];

            sir[0] = r[p];
            sir[1] = g[p];
            sir[2] = b[p];

            rinSum += sir[0];
            ginSum += sir[1];
            binSum += sir[2];

            rSum += rinSum;
            gSum += ginSum;
            bSum += binSum;

            env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(sirArray, sir, 0);
            stackPointer = (stackPointer + 1) % div;
            sirArray = env->NewIntArray(stackPointer);
            sir = env->GetIntArrayElements(sirArray, NULL);

            routSum += sir[0];
            goutSum += sir[1];
            boutSum += sir[2];

            rinSum -= sir[0];
            ginSum -= sir[1];
            binSum -= sir[2];

            yi += width;
            env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(sirArray, sir, 0);
        }
    }

    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in_, in, 0);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out_, in, 0);
}
```

Comment: code in c++ @JornVernee

Comment: It's a lot of code, I'd suggest splitting it up into several functions, and only use minimal JNI code to wrap the algorithm. That would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Why is there a `ReleaseIntArrayElements(out_, in, 0)` call? You never did `GetIntArrayElements` on `out_`. And why are you creating temporary Java arrays with `NewIntArray` that are used only for internal calculations in your C++ code? That makes no sense at all to me. Just use C++ arrays or containers for that.